# Do more unoccupied covalent bonds decrease resistence?

Tags: resistance

In this image of a P-N junction, there are unoccupied slots for electrons. There are also extra electrons.

[image: PN]

As you can see there are missing holes, which electrons are to flow when it has voltage.

Aluminum has 1 less electron (in valence shell) than silicon, and phosphorus has 1 more electron (in valence shell) than silicon. Notice that there is an about 1:1 ratio of aluminum to silicon (on negative side) and a 1:1 ratio of phosphorus to silicon (on positive side)

So there could be more aluminum/phosphorus or there could be less. It seems like more electrons would flow if I increased the silicon/phosphorus.

If I increase the amount of aluminum/phosphorus atoms relative to silicon atoms, would the resistence decrease? (and vice versa)

Comment: Yes, as you increase the dopant and introduce conduction band electrons the material behaves more like a conductor. The magic of semiconductor junctions is supplying just enough dopant to get the additional (or lack of) electrons while not impacting the crystal lattice macroscopically. In semiconductors current "flows through" the  lattice as opposed to hoping between individual atoms like you might have imagined. Semiconductor junctions are fundamentally a crystalline structure. The physics is also somewhere in between a tightly bound molecule and random atoms w/valence electrons.

Comment: @crasic what does "...while not impacting the crystal lattice macroscopically" mean?

Comment: @Walter It means that too much dopant would change the crystal structure, but small amounts can be accommodated within the usual crystal structure of silicon.